# Find max (or min) value that exists in two Redis sorted sets

Tags: redis

Is there a single Redis command that can help me find the maximum (or minimum) score that is common to two sorted sets?

For example, given these sets:

Set 1 (score / key)

- 1 "one"
- 2 "two"
- 5 "five"

Set 2 (score / key)

- 2 "two"
- 3 "three"
- 5 "five"

The *maximum* score that falls *within the range* of both sets would be 3. And the *minimum* score would be 2. Is there a way to find this quickly and easily in Redis? I know I can iterate in code over one of the sets and test those values against the other set or examine ZPOPMAX/ZPOPMIN but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no command in redis which can solve your question directly. However, you can join the two sets into a new set by using the redis command [`ZUNIONSTORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zunionstore) and you can find the minimum and maximum in the new set.

Answer (score 1):

@Gunasekar's answer is correct, just pointing out two additional options:

1. Use a Lua script to iterate server-side over the smaller set, calling ZSCORE on each element in the other set to filter until you get the first match. This would be the O(N*logM) in the worst case.
2. For every such pair of zsets, maintain the min/max member at runtime. This will add complexity to updating members/scores and could result in write amplification problems but it provides very fast reads.